# How can I prevent a Java HttpURLConnection from using NTLM

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I have a case where the user doesn't want us to use NTLM to connect.  But when we call getResponseCode(); on the HttpURLConnection object, it automatically tries NTLM after the server rejects basic authorization.
I looked inside the HttpURLConnection source code and I do not see a way to avoid it.  How can I prevent it?

Comment: Don;'t use urlconnection?

Comment: @Antoniossss I think that is what I am going to have to do, I don't think HttpURLConnection will let me avoid id.  I am looking into Apache's httpcomponents now.